# Pivot tidyr in R

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

(Snipped of data included)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0G7.png)

Trying to create a long data set using pivot_longer(). Tried the following code:

```
pivot_longer(problemset7, cols = c(time1, time2, time3, time4), names_to = "time", names_prefix = NULL,
             names_sep = NULL, names_pattern = NULL, names_ptypes = list(),
             names_repair = "check_unique", values_to = "value",
             values_drop_na = FALSE, values_ptypes = list())
```

With the following error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"             values_drop_na = FALSE, values_ptypes = list()
pivot_longer"
>              names_sep = NULL, names_pattern = NULL, names_ptypes = list(),
Error: unexpected ',' in "             names_sep = NULL,"
>              names_repair = "check_unique", values_to = "value",
Error: unexpected ',' in "             names_repair = "check_unique","
>              values_drop_na = FALSE, values_ptypes = list())
Error: unexpected ',' in "             values_drop_na = FALSE,"
```

Any advice?

Data set: dput(problemset7)

Comment: Please provide the `problemset7` dataframe using `dput`.

Comment: Those errors are indicative of code different from what you provided: it suggests that you have a previous call to `pivot_longer` that is missing a right-paren. But since *this* code does not produce those errors (and we don't have sample data), this is unfortunately not something we can reproduce.

Comment: Writing `dput(data)` doesn't give us your data—we need the actual output of running that code. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on including data in a post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"             values_drop_na = FALSE, values_ptypes = list()
pivot_longer"
```

See this line here? It's telling you that before your `pivot_longer` line, there was a line that ended with `values_drop_na = FALSE, values_ptypes = list()`, and is clearly missing a second closing parenthesis after the `list()` (i.e., should be `list())`).

That should fix it.